# Tree with nested node class compiles, but inserting nodes return null

Tags: java

I am trying to insert a node into my tree using Node as a nested class. I can't figure out why the `tree.root` won't save the node using my method `insertNode`

```
public class Tree {
  Node root;

  private class Node {
    int value;
    Node(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.insertNode(4, tree.root);
    System.out.println(tree.root);

  }

  public void insertNode(int value, Node n){
    if(n == null ){
      n = new Node(value);
    }
  }   

}

>> null
```

What am I missing?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Which parts of your code you don't understand what they do?

Comment: @nbro I think the problem is that when I use insertNode, the Node that I save to tree.root, is not saved outside the method. Outside its scope? I don't understand why that is

Comment: "the Node that I save to tree.root", where are you saving it? Hint: nowhere. `n` is a reference to an object, not a field of the object you want to add a node to. Do some research on the difference between references and objects and between variables, arguments, fields, etc, in Java.

Comment: @Siguza That link helped! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code does is the following:

1. It creates a new `Tree`. The `root` `Node` will be initialized by the compiler to the default value `null`.
2. You are "inserting" something into the `Tree` at least this is what the method name suggests. In fact, the method does nothing except to set an argument to a default value if it is null.
3. You are printing out the `root` `Node` of your `Tree` which is `null`.

I think you should change your `insertNode` method so it actually modifies the state of your `Tree`.

Edit: As I read the comments below your question I noticed something that I missed at first. In your `insertNode` method you probably intended to do exactly what I described above. But what you do is something different: You assign something to a local variable instead of a member variable. Written in an explicit notation you want to do this instead:

```
this.root = new Node(value)
```

The difference is that in your code `n` is not bound to the object but `Tree.root` is meaning that changes (more precisely, assignments) to `n` will not be persistent and will void when the method returns. If you assign an object to `Tree.root` then this change will be reflected in the `Tree` object.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do now. After reading about 'Is Java “pass-by-reference” ', and you answer, I think the answer is to say

'tree.insertNode(5); void insertNode(int v){this.root = new Node(v);}` 

But the next step, building a binary tree, confuses me. Should I edit this question? Or start a new one?

Comment: You did answer my question :) So I accepted your answer. Thank you!